# Extracting emails out of a listview with a button and email those people their passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have created a "Register All Players" button. Once clicked, I want it to get the email of all players in the listview and take that email and email them their passwords all at once. This is what I have so far. (When I click the button, nothing happens). I am not sure what's happening, but If i could guess I am not getting those emails properly. This is my code behind for it and the image is what the page looks like. Thank you.

[Picture of what the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGGwt.png)

```
    protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (ListViewDataItem item in livPlayer.Items)

        {

            // Get the Player Email
            TextBox txtEmailAddress = item.FindControl("txtEmailAddress") as TextBox;
            String EmailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text;
            Convert.ToInt32(EmailAddress);

            // Develop the SQL call.
            String strSQL = "";
            strSQL = "SELECT FirstName + ' ' + MiddleInitial + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, Password";
            strSQL += " FROM Player ";
            strSQL += "WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress ";

            //Establish a network connection to the SQL Server database.
            SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2018IFSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            // Set up the SQL command object.
            SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            objSqlCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;
            objSqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            objSqlCommand.CommandText = strSQL;

            // Open the connection and execute the data reader.
            objSqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader objSqlDataReader = objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            //// Define the input parameters
            objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text);

            ////attempt to retrieve the row from the table
            if (objSqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                //Save the full name and password.
                String strFullName = objSqlDataReader["FullName"].ToString();
                String strPassword = objSqlDataReader["Password"].ToString();

                //Close the data reader and the connection
                objSqlDataReader.Close();
                objSqlConnection.Close();

                //Build the email message.
                MailMessage objMailMessageSend = new MailMessage();
                objMailMessageSend.Subject = "IFS: Player Registration";
                objMailMessageSend.Body = "Congratulations " + strFullName + "," + "<br /><br />You have been registered as a player in the Indiana Futbol system. Please retain the following password as you will need it to login to the system.<br /><br />Password: <i>" + strPassword + "</i><br /><br />Indiana Futbol System.";
                objMailMessageSend.From = new MailAddress("noreply@franklincollege.com");
                objMailMessageSend.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text));
                objMailMessageSend.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //send email message.
                SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                objSmtpClient.Send(objMailMessageSend);

                //set the message.
                this.Master.MessageForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                this.Master.Message = "Player was added and registered successfully. The password was sent to their email.";
            }
            else
            {
                // close the data reader and the connecion.
                objSqlDataReader.Close();
                objSqlConnection.Close();
                this.Master.MessageForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
                this.Master.Message = "Adding and registering failed. Please submit this problem to GrizSquad.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and confirm that the code execution enters the for loop? Also, why is the emailAddress converted to integer `Convert.ToInt32(EmailAddress);`?

Comment: You're planning on sending passwords through email, in plain text?

Comment: Never send passwords via plain text email. Send them a link to go in and change their password. That is a security disaster in the making.

Comment: @IrishChieftain this is a project for class, so It will not go on real servers. Thank you for the concern!

Comment: @Matt.G If I comment out the     Convert.ToInt32(EmailAddress) and  run a break point and I get an error when I hit line 
SqlDataReader objSqlDataReader = objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader(); gives me the error (Must declare the scalar variable "@EmailAddress"). If i leave (convert.To) and run a break point it crashes as well because it isnt in the right format.

Comment: @Matt.G I figure out the problem with that breakpoint! I needed to define the input parameters before I opened the connection.

Comment: Great!! Few other things you might want to consider: Open (and close) the SQLConnection outside the for loop, to avoid opening and closing of connection mulitple times. Even better, try to come up with a sql query for all the email addresses in one go (for e.g. `Where EmailAddress IN (<list of emailaddresses)` ). This will reduce the network traffic.

Comment: @Matt.G Okay, thank you for the advise. I will give this a shot!